# About OneIdentity

Tags: pattern-matching, attributes

The document says:

> OneIdentity
>   is an attribute that can be assigned to a symbol f to indicate that f[x], f[f[x]], etc. are all equivalent to x for the purpose of pattern matching.

Consider the expressions below:

```
In[1]:= SetAttributes[f, OneIdentity]
In[2]:= Nest[f, x, 10]    
Out[2]= f[f[f[f[f[f[f[f[f[f[x]]]]]]]]]]
```

We cannot get f[x] as the document says.

```
In[1]:= MatchQ[x, Times[n_. , x_]]
Out[1]= True
```

Also, the example in the document seems a little confusing.  What does the pattern `Times[n_.,x_]`  mean?

I'm quite confused about it. Please explains this.

Comment: It treats the expression as equivalent to x *for the purpose of pattern matching*. It doesn't *evaluate* to x.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What the documentation means is that for a symbol `f` with attribute `OneIdentity`, pattern forms like `f[_.,x]`, `f[_.,f[_.,x]]`, etc. (Note the *Possible Issues* section!) will not only match expression like `f[4,a]` but also an expression without a Head `f`.

Take the `CirclePlus`, which has no built-in meaning or any attribute, as an example.

```
Clear[CirclePlus]
ClearAttributes[CirclePlus, Attributes@CirclePlus];
DefaultValues[CirclePlus] = {};
Attributes[CirclePlus]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

This will work as expected:

```
k⊕y /. a_⊕x_ :> {a, x}
k⊕y /. a_.⊕x_ :> {a, x}
```

> ```
> {k, y}
> {k, y}
> ```

But this won't work because `a_.⊕x_` or `(a_:1)⊕x_` won't match `y`:

```
y /. a_.⊕x_ :> {a, x}
y /. (a_: 1)⊕x_ :> {a, x}
```

> ```
> y
> y
> ```

Instead of introducing a special rule like `x_:>{1,x}`, we can add the `OneIdentity` to `CirclePlus`:

```
SetAttributes[CirclePlus, OneIdentity]
```

Now this works as well:

```
y /. (a_: 1)⊕x_ /; (Echo[a]; True) :> {a, x}
```

> ```
> 1
> {1, y}
> ```

This still won't work

```
y /. a_.⊕x_ :> {a, x}
```

until `CirclePlus` gets `DefaultValues`:

```
Default[CirclePlus] := RandomReal[];
```

Now `a_.⊕x_` will match `y`:

```
y /. a_.⊕x_ /; (Echo[a]; True) :> {a, x}
```

> ```
> 0.217426
> {0.217426, y}
> ```

And nested `CirclePlus` will also match `y`:

```
y /. a_.⊕(b_.⊕x_) /; (Echo[{a, b}]; True) :> {a, b, x}
```

> ```
> {0.934169, 0.157904}
> {0.934169, 0.157904, y}
> ```

```
y /. a_.⊕(x_⊕b_.) /; (Echo[{a, b}]; True) :> {a, b, x}
```

> ```
> {0.319821, 0.490549}
> {0.319821, 0.490549, y}
> ```

or match `4⊕y`:

```
4⊕y /. a_.⊕(x_⊕b_.) /; (Echo[{a, b}]; True) :> {a, b, x}
```

> ```
> {4, 0.861579}
> {4, 0.861579, y}
> ```

Comment: @ShutaoTang I'm a bit of busy this year. (But I still visit the site regularly!)

Comment: @Silvia 膜巨神……话说还有那些中国人在这里？感觉完全认不全