# Subtle order-of-evaluation issues when pattern-matching with attributes

Tags: evaluation, pattern-matching, attributes

Related question concerning unrolling the tests that are shown below:

[Big and Little surprises when unrolling tests of pattern-matching and attributes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183319/big-and-little-surprises-when-unrolling-tests-of-pattern-matching-and-attributes)

Questions researched before posting this one:

[Orderless pattern matching](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71463/orderless-pattern-matching)

[Combinations of multiple matching patterns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/105608/combinations-of-multiple-matching-patterns)

[About OneIdentity](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124372/about-oneidentity)

[What has changed in pattern matching functions with the Orderless attribute?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121564/what-has-changed-in-pattern-matching-functions-with-the-orderless-attribute)

[Transformation rule for arbitrary number of argument expressions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121535/transformation-rule-for-arbitrary-number-of-argument-expressions?noredirect=1#comment329951_121535)

[Pattern does not match with Orderless head](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94432/pattern-does-not-match-with-orderless-head)

In an attempt to understand pattern-matching better, I tried some exhaustive
testing of a certain substitution rule under all seven combinations of
attributes, leaving out the null case of no attributes:

```
In[1]:= allAtts =
 Flatten[Table[
   Union[Sort /@
     Permutations[{Flat, Orderless, OneIdentity}, {i}]], {i, 3}], 1]
Out[1]= {{Flat}, {OneIdentity}, {Orderless}, {Flat, OneIdentity}, {Flat,
  Orderless}, {OneIdentity, Orderless}, {Flat, OneIdentity,
  Orderless}}
```

The substitution rule attempts to match the pattern `eqv[x_, y_]` against the input `eqv[p, q, r]` to see what gets bound to `x` and `y` for each combination of attributes.

In the first test, I define the substitution before setting the attributes. After some manual prettification of the output:

```
In[2]:= Table[Module[{e = (eqv[p, q, r] /. {eqv[x_, y_] :> {x, y}})},
    ClearAll[eqv];
    SetAttributes[eqv, j];
    {j, First@e, Rest@e}],
  {j, allAtts}]
Out[2]= {{{Flat},                         p, eqv[q, r]},
         {{OneIdentity},                  eqv[p], {eqv[q, r]}},
         {{Orderless},                    p, eqv[q, r]},
         {{Flat, OneIdentity},            p, eqv[q, r]},
         {{Flat, Orderless},              p, {eqv[q, r]}},
         {{OneIdentity, Orderless},       q, {eqv[p, r]}},
         {{Flat, OneIdentity, Orderless}, p, eqv[q, r]}}
```

The results are reasonable, plausible, interpretable.

In a second test (not-unrolled; see cited question above), I set the attributes before defining the substitution rule. The results are subtly different.

```
In[3]:= Table[Module[{e},
    ClearAll[eqv];
    SetAttributes[eqv, j];
    e = (eqv[p, q, r] /. {eqv[x_, y_] :> {x, y}});
    {j, First@e, Rest@e}],
  {j, allAtts}]
Out[3]= {{{Flat},                         eqv[p], {eqv[q, r]}}, (* difft *)
         {{OneIdentity},                  p, eqv[q, r]},        (* difft *)
         {{Orderless},                    p, eqv[q, r]},
         {{Flat, OneIdentity},            p, {eqv[q, r]}},      (* difft *)
         {{Flat, Orderless},              q, {eqv[p, r]}},      (* difft *)
         {{OneIdentity, Orderless},       p, eqv[q, r]},        (* difft *)
         {{Flat, OneIdentity, Orderless}, p, {eqv[q, r]}}}      (* difft *)
```

My questions are:

1. Why, exactly, are there such differences? I understand that order-of-evaluation matters quite a bit, in general, in Mathematica, but it's hard for me to understand these particular differences. Details follow in the rest of my questions:
2. In the first test, with `Flat` alone, why do I get (a) `p` wrapped in `eqv`, i.e., `eqv[p]` and `eqv[q, r]` wrapped in `List`, when I set attributes before defining the substitution rule?
3. In the second test, for `OneIdentity`, alone, when attributes are set before the substitution rule is defined, do I get the same results as for `Flat`, alone, when the substitution rule is defined before the attributes are set? In other words, for the two orders of attributes-setttings versus rule-defining, are the results for `Flat` alone and `OneIdentity` alone swapped?
4. In the fourth test, for `{Flat, OneIdentity}`, why do I get no wrapping with `List` for the second substitution (for `y`) when the substitution rule is defined before the attributes are set, and yes wrapping with `List` when the attributes are set before the substitution rule is defined?
5. In the fifth test, for `{Flat, Orderless}`, why do I get `p` for `x` when the substitution rule is defined before attributes are set, and `q` for `x` when the attributes are set before the substitution rule is defined?
6. In the sixth test, for `{OneIdentity, Orderless}`, there are two differences between the two conditions (substitution rule defined before attributes  set, and attributes set before substitution rule defined). The first difference (a) is that I get `q` for `x` in the first condition and `p` for `x` in the second condition. The second difference (b) is that I get `List` wrapping in the first condition and no `List` wrapping in the second condition.

**EDIT**: I missed the last difference in the original, and finding it gave me an opportunity to ask the sharpest questions:

7. In the seventh test, for all three attributes, I get an extra `List` wrapping in the output in the second condition, attributes-set before substitution-defined. Why is that? Should I have been able to predict it knowing just the conditions? By what reasoning?

I apologize for the length and complexity of this question, but I made it as short and as simple as I know how to.  This question reveals that I don't know nearly as much as I thought I did about pattern-matching and attributes. Perhaps after I learn more from you-all, a much simpler form of the essential question --- hiding in here somewhere I hope --- will emerge.

Comment: First, it makes no sense to set attributes after doing the replacement. Second, the only time the replacement rule will fire is when Flat is one of the attributes. If you include `e` in your output, you will see that the replacement only did something when Flat was one of the attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Carl Woll's comment turned the lights on for me and cleared the fog. There are no matches when there is no `Flat`. That observation also clears up the related question [Big and Little surprises when unrolling tests of pattern-matching and attributes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183319/big-and-little-surprises-when-unrolling-tests-of-pattern-matching-and-attributes).

Here are the only tests that make sense out of the above, now unrolled.

```
In[16]:= Module[{}, ClearAll[eqv]; SetAttributes[eqv, {Flat}];
 eqv[p, q, r] /. {eqv[x_, y_] :> {x, y}}]

Out[16]= {eqv[p], eqv[q, r]}

In[17]:= Module[{}, ClearAll[eqv];
 SetAttributes[eqv, {Flat, OneIdentity}];
 eqv[p, q, r] /. {eqv[x_, y_] :> {x, y}}]

Out[17]= {p, eqv[q, r]}

In[18]:= Module[{}, ClearAll[eqv];
 SetAttributes[eqv, {Flat, Orderless}];
 eqv[p, q, r] /. {eqv[x_, y_] :> {x, y}}]

Out[18]= {q, eqv[p, r]}

In[19]:= Module[{}, ClearAll[eqv];
 SetAttributes[eqv, {Flat, OneIdentity, Orderless}];
 eqv[p, q, r] /. {eqv[x_, y_] :> {x, y}}]

Out[19]= {p, eqv[q, r]}
```

The answer for `{Flat, Orderless}` seems puzzling. Usually, Mathematica sorts symbolic constants alphabetically and minimizes nesting, leading us to expect `{p,eqv[q,r}`. There are an unbounded number of correct answers, all equivalent under these attributes, however, any of which would be acceptable. Here are just a few:

```
In[54]:= ClearAll[eqv]; SetAttributes[eqv, {Flat, Orderless}];
eqv[eqv[p], eqv[r, q]] === eqv[eqv[q], eqv[p, r]] === 
 eqv[eqv[q], eqv[r, p]] === eqv[eqv[q], eqv[r, p]] === 
 eqv[eqv[r], eqv[p, q]] === eqv[eqv[r], eqv[q, p]] === 
 eqv[p, eqv[r, q]] === eqv[q, eqv[p, r]] === 
 eqv[eqv[eqv[p]], eqv[q, r]] === eqv[eqv[p], q, r]

Out[55]= True
```

Indeed, even the result for `Flat` alone has many correct answers:

```
In[58]:= ClearAll[eqv]; SetAttributes[eqv, {Flat}];
eqv[eqv[p], eqv[q, r]] === eqv[p, eqv[q, r]] === 
 eqv[eqv[eqv[p]], eqv[q, r]] === eqv[eqv[p], q, r]

Out[59]= True
```

Comment: You can use `ReplaceList` to show all possible replacements. It is an open question as to why the `{Flat,Orderless}` case is not giving the first element fro the `ReplaceList` result.